# Thermal POS Printer using ethernet in flutter

Tags: flutter, printing, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I am working on a restaurant app where I have to generate the receipt using a thermal printer via Ethernet. I am using the `eos_pos_printer` library. When I put the IP address of the device I got the error. Printer connection timeout. Here is the code below:

```
import 'package:esc_pos_printer/esc_pos_printer.dart';

const PaperSize paper = PaperSize.mm80;
final profile = await CapabilityProfile.load();
final printer = NetworkPrinter(paper, profile);

final PosPrintResult res = await printer.connect('192.168.0.123', port: 9100);

if (res == PosPrintResult.success) {
  testReceipt(printer);
  printer.disconnect();
}

print('Print result: ${res.msg}');

void testReceipt(NetworkPrinter printer) {
  printer.text(
        'Regular: aA bB cC dD eE fF gG hH iI jJ kK lL mM nN oO pP qQ rR sS tT uU vV wW xX yY zZ');
  printer.text('Special 1: àÀ èÈ éÉ ûÛ üÜ çÇ ôÔ',
      styles: PosStyles(codeTable: 'CP1252'));
  printer.text('Special 2: blåbærgrød',
      styles: PosStyles(codeTable: 'CP1252'));

  printer.text('Bold text', styles: PosStyles(bold: true));
  printer.text('Reverse text', styles: PosStyles(reverse: true));
  printer.text('Underlined text',
      styles: PosStyles(underline: true), linesAfter: 1);
  printer.text('Align left', styles: PosStyles(align: PosAlign.left));
  printer.text('Align center', styles: PosStyles(align: PosAlign.center));
  printer.text('Align right',
      styles: PosStyles(align: PosAlign.right), linesAfter: 1);

  printer.text('Text size 200%',
      styles: PosStyles(
        height: PosTextSize.size2,
        width: PosTextSize.size2,
      ));

  printer.feed(2);
  printer.cut();
}
```

The printer that I am using is Epson T20III.